# OAuth2 code endpoint org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I tried to implement OAuth2 in my Spring Boot Rest service with Authorization Server. But when I sent request for authorization code I got 401 Unauthorized and Access Denied exception.

GET http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=oidc-client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/code

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig {


    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http
                .oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServer -> resourceServer
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.sessionManagement(s -> s.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withUsername("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .issuer("http://localhost:8080")
                .build();
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
# Security
spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=password
spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.oidc-client.registration.client-id=oidc-client
spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.oidc-client.registration.client-secret=secret
spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.oidc-client.registration.client-authentication-methods=client_secret_basic
spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.oidc-client.registration.authorization-grant-types=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.oidc-client.registration.redirect-uris=http://localhost:8080/code
spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.oidc-client.registration.post-logout-redirect-uris=http://localhost:8080/logout
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**Error**

```
2024-03-26T09:00:10.549+02:00 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=oidc-client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/code
2024-03-26T09:00:10.549+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.564+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.564+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.564+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationServerContextFilter (4/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.564+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (5/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.564+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (6/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.564+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match And [CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS], Not [Or [org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$1639/0x0000016e29af0450@262c57f7, org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer$BearerTokenRequestMatcher@7589cd0c]]]
2024-03-26T09:00:10.564+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OidcLogoutEndpointFilter (7/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.564+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (8/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.564+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2024-03-26T09:00:10.564+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter (9/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.564+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter (10/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.564+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2024-03-26T09:00:10.564+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-03-26T09:00:10.564+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider (1/18)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] izationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider : Retrieved registered client
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] izationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider : Validated authorization code request parameters
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] izationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider : Did not authenticate authorization code request since principal not authenticated
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2DeviceVerificationEndpointFilter (11/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter (12/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter (13/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter (14/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter (15/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.r.w.a.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Did not process request since did not find bearer token
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (16/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (17/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (18/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (19/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.580+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (20/25)
2024-03-26T09:00:10.596+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@6915e70c]
2024-03-26T09:00:10.596+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@6915e70c] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@4ba1b76e
2024-03-26T09:00:10.596+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-03-26T09:00:10.596+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.3.jar:1.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.3.jar:1.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter.java:86) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.3.jar:1.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2DeviceVerificationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2DeviceVerificationEndpointFilter.java:139) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.1.3.jar:1.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]

2024-03-26T09:00:10.674+02:00 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=oidc-client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/code&continue to session
2024-03-26T09:00:10.674+02:00 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using Or [Ant [pattern='/oauth2/token', POST], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/introspect', POST], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/revoke', POST], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/device_authorization', POST]]
2024-03-26T09:00:10.674+02:00 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using Or [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer$BearerTokenRequestMatcher@7589cd0c, RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest], And [Not [MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@55725d48, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@55725d48, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@55725d48, matchingMediaTypes=[*/*], useEquals=true, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]]
2024-03-26T09:00:10.674+02:00 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint@555f5e39
2024-03-26T09:00:10.674+02:00 TRACE 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2024-03-26T09:00:49.501+02:00  INFO 8592 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

I hope for your help.